# Firebase storage throws authentication error on Android Things

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, android-things

Since Android Things SDK does not support Firebase Authentication, when connecting to Firebase Storage, I receive the error:

> W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
>
> > E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqn: Please sign in before trying to get a token.

This error is repeated several times (several seconds) then eventually uploads.  **Any suggestion on how to anonymously upload to Firebase Storage without the Firebase Authentication Package and without runtime errors?**

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think this may be achieved is by looking at:

- how the Web API for Authentication performs authentication, then make your own REST calls from your app to retrieve access token (please be aware you also need to refresh the token when it expires)
- how the Web API for Storage performs requests on the network, so you can mimic the behaviour, which will have to be reimplemented with some REST library

Have a read [here](https://www.novoda.com/blog/firebase-on-amazon-devices/) to know what you can actually do with and without Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

I used [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) in my recent project.

In my case the process is as follows

1. send the UID over bluetooth
2. [Create custom token with the UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)
3. [Sign in with the custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth)